# How to stop timestamp from pr command

Tags: linux, command-line

What is causing the timestamp written in the output file?

```
pr - mJ <(ls -d /dir1/dir2/*/) <(sh /dir1/dir2/text.txt) > /dir1/dir2/output.txt
```

When i view the output file

```
cat /dir/dir/output.txt

2019-03-20 10:56                                    Page 1

dir11    45 
dir12    56
dir13    83
```

What is causing the timestamp?

List all directories under /dir1/dir2/

```
ls -d /dir1/dir2/*/
```

Content of /dir1/dir2/text.txt

```
ls -lR "/dir1/dir2/dir11/" | wc -l
ls -lR "/dir1/dir2/dir12/" | wc -l
ls -lR "/dir1/dir2/dir13/" | wc -l
```

Comment: `pr` is a page formatter for printing files. By default it adds a page header. Turn it off with `-T`

Comment: `.txt` is an unconventional file extension for a file that contains a shell script.